# Set up a file filter in QT Designer for QGSFileWidget

Tags: qt-designer

How would I set a file filter for QGSFileWidget for multiple file types, xlsx, csv etc

I've worked out where:
[image]

But I'm unsure what the string needs to look like - what separator to use etc?
I'm new to QT Designer and I'm not sure where to find documentation with examples on the widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsFileWidget.html#qgis.gui.QgsFileWidget.setFilter .

Try setting the filter to

```
All files (*.*);;JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg);;TIFF (*.tif)
```

As per the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604542 that relates to the standard QT File Dialog.